# Pulling data from one spreadsheet to another with VLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

There is a spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15p-dIBrLbzVVCcVwezAjtslLZ3mES9BSTIXfz7khYNk/edit#gid=0
the second column "Status" should contain the data which is pulled with the formula
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1gWeOD2L3Ytfr5UqkicCaakqjLawdjFvWOHYikA7jNPk","Internal!A:G"),7, FALSE)))

from this file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gWeOD2L3Ytfr5UqkicCaakqjLawdjFvWOHYikA7jNPk/edit#gid=0

For some reasons, it does not pull the data, simply gives empty cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,
 IMPORTRANGE("1gWeOD2L3Ytfr5UqkicCaakqjLawdjFvWOHYikA7jNPk",
 "Internal!A:G"), 7, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you plz let me know where my issue was, still cannot get it. It seems to me my formula was ok.

Comment: @Hanna you used `A2` only instead of `A2:A` to take advantage of ARRAYFORMULA. see your sheet

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. On my internal working files, I am doing the same thing. But the data does not show up. I checked all the files are in the shared status. I also changed the code (e.g. "1gWeOD2L3Ytfr5UqkicCaakqjLawdjFvWOHYikA7jNPk") to the full url (e.g. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gWeOD2L3Ytfr5UqkicCaakqjLawdjFvWOHYikA7jNPk/edit#gid=0), still does not see the data there. May be, you can give me a clue what the reason might be?

Comment: @Hanna first you need to run IMPORTRANGE separately to "allow access" to connect your sheets. you also do not need to use full url. id is just fine. and lastly, make sure all ranges check-up

Comment: oh silly me! I completely forgot about this step. Thank you very much!